# Calculate Max Width and Height

Tags: math, pixel

I need to calculate the width and height of X number of elements based on the overall width and height of the screen in pixels so I can write a function. The individual elements x and y should be the same for each element.

I know the height and width of the screen but the number of elements could vary.

For example, if I have 20 elements/buttons, I want them to take up the whole screen and likewise, if I have 10 elements/buttons, I want them to take up the whole screen.

Example: Screen is 628x1289 and I have 20 elements. How can I calculate the size of each element?

This is similar to web responsive but it's not for a web application so I need to figure out how to calculate it using the pixels.

I hope that makes sense but please let me know if it doesn't.

Steve

P.S. This seems relevant but I'm no math expert so have no idea exactly what they're saying...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Seems like they already know the size of the objects which is the opposite to my needs. I have a space and want to know what x and y I need to set each object to fit the space.

Comment: Divide the width by the number of elements? Exclude spaces between elements if any

Comment: Place them in some rows? And what to do  if you have 13 elements (or another prime number)?

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc that's the easy part but what about the height? I want them to fill up the whole screen not just the width.

Comment: Since you mention responsive web perhaps you could specify the CSS styling / media queries that you'd like to reproduce?

Comment: This is NOT web based as I said so CSS is not appropriate.

Comment: How is it different for width than height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many free parameters. Make some restrictions to solve the task.

Example: Let's element proportions (width/height ratio) are equal to screen proportions

```
 C = ScreenWidth / ScreenHeight
```

Now let's unknown element height is `h`, so width is `w = C * h`

So every row may contain `ScreenWidth div (C * h)`, every column `ScreenHeight div h`, where `div` is integer division.

Now you can find solution (max `h` value) of inequality

```
 numberX <= (ScreenWidth div (C * h)) * (ScreenHeight div h)
```

and get height and width of numberX elements filling the screen (last row might be incomplete)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read it over a few times but still can't quite understand it. :( I'll keep trying and hopefully it'll start to make sense.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how do it automatically so I've left it as a user input. It may be a better solution actually. Thanks for your help!